# How prove the left hand side

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How can I prove that (the left hand side)

For any two subsets A and B of X prove that
$ (A\setminus B)\cup B=A \iff  B\subset A $

Comment: you need to prove two implications. Equality of sets is proven by showing two inclusions hold. Inclusions are shown by taking an element in a set and proving it is contained in the other set.

Comment: @Student I know that but how about this (A\B) union B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(A\setminus B)\cup B=A \implies  B\subset A$

We need to show that $b\in B \implies b\in A$

Suppose it is not true.

Choose a $b\in B$ that is not in $A$

$b\in (A\setminus B)\cup B\\
(A\setminus B)\cup B \ne A$

Contradiction.

$B\subset A \implies (A\setminus B)\cup B=A$

All $b \in B$ are in $A$

if $b\in B$ then $(A\setminus B)\cup B$
if $a$ in $A$ but  in $B$ then $a\in(A\setminus B)$

Comment: Thanks , but why you wrote in the line 5 and 6 (A\B) union A not union B same the question?

Comment: @user510071 typo.  Thanks, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

$B \subset X\cup B$ for any set.

So $A = X\cup B$ means $B \subset A$ for any $X$ and is true for $X = A\setminus B$ and where $A = (A\setminus B) \cup B$.  So $\implies$ is done.

If $B \subset A$ then $B\setminus A = \emptyset$ and $B \cap A = B$. So $(A\setminus B) \cup B = (A\setminus B)\cup (A\cap B) = (A\cap B^c) \cup (A\cap B) = A \cap (B^c \cup B) = A \cap U = A$ (where $U$ is the universal set).  So $\Leftarrow$ is done.